# How do I change the @INC variable to use BioPerl?

Tags: permissions, perl

I have successfully installed BioPerl.

When I try to use the objects I get an error `cannot locate Bio.seq.pm in @INC .....`

The "build" programs put everything in the "download" directory.

I am having trouble moving the files to `/usr/bin` and suspect that maybe adding the "download" directory to the @INC paths might be easier.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install BioPerl? Did you install via `sudo apt-get install bioperl`? What are you using to build programs?

Answer (score 1):

The variable @INC is defined when Perl is compiled and it is embedded in the binary code.

The @inc array can be changed by modifying the `PERL5LIB` variable, from the command line, like so:

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/foobar/code
```

You can add this to either your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`(the preferred location) to make this change permanent.

Additionally, you can use the following in your script code:

```
use lib '/home/foobar/code';
```